# How to override set property method using nsubstitute

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, nsubstitute

In a unit test I've substituted all my Views when registering them using nsubstitute.
However when I go to dispose of 1 of the views it throws an error when setting 1 of the properties (of type object) to null. The error is "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: collection"

As a workaround I would like to use nsubstitute to intercept the set method on this property and when the argument is null then either ignore it, or set it to something else.

I've tried many variations and I think When..Do is what I need, but no luck implementing it. Here is my last attempt:

```
var view = Substitute.For(new[] { registration.Interface }, new object[] { });
view.When(x => x.DataContext = Arg.Is<object>(null)).Do(x => x[0] = new object());
```

FYI here is the stack trace of the nsubstitute error:

```
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)  
at NSubstitute.Core.Arguments.SuppliedArgumentSpecifications..ctor(IDefaultChecker     defaultChecker, IEnumerable`1 argumentSpecifications)  
at NSubstitute.Core.Arguments.SuppliedArgumentSpecificationsFactory.Create(IEnumerable`1 argumentSpecifications)  
at NSubstitute.Core.Arguments.MixedArgumentSpecificationsFactory.Create(IList`1 argumentSpecs, Object[] arguments, IParameterInfo[] parameterInfos)  
at NSubstitute.Core.Arguments.ArgumentSpecificationsFactory.Create(IList`1 argumentSpecs, Object[] arguments, IParameterInfo[] parameterInfos, MatchArgs matchArgs)  
at NSubstitute.Core.CallSpecificationFactory.CreateFrom(ICall call, MatchArgs matchArgs)  
at NSubstitute.Core.GetCallSpec.FromCall(ICall call, MatchArgs matchArgs)  
at NSubstitute.Core.ConfigureCall.SetResultForCall(ICall call, IReturn valueToReturn, MatchArgs matchArgs)   
at NSubstitute.Routing.Handlers.PropertySetterHandler.Handle(ICall call)  
at NSubstitute.Routing.Route.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Handle>b__0(ICallHandler x)  
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()  
at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)  
at NSubstitute.Routing.Route.Handle(ICall call)  
at NSubstitute.Core.CallRouter.Route(ICall call)  
at NSubstitute.Proxies.CastleDynamicProxy.CastleForwardingInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)  
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
```

Comment: Do you need to set the `DataContext`, rather than the argument value? So `view.When(...).Do(x => view.DataContext = new object())`? Can you provide more of the code involved? I'd like to try and help with the dispose prob before trying the workaround.

Comment: @DavidTchepak yes the DataContext is being set to null when the view is disposed. It works fine apart from the unit test failing because of the dispose throwing this exception. Every line in this project is a custom function so there is too much code to share, but this is called in the **viewmodel** OnDispose() which 1) calls base.OnDispose, 2) disposes of the view, 3) removes event handlers from viewmodel, 4) removes eventhandlers from view, 5) sets the datacontext of the view to null (ERROR!), 6) sets the view to null.

Comment: I've also tried `view.When(x => x.DataContext = Arg.Is<object>(null)).Do(x => view.DataContext = new object());` but it throws a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error on the When clause.

Comment: more information: I've managed to narrow down the exception being thrown if everything is disposed automatically at the end of the test. If I explicitly call `.Dispose()` on each view in the teardown then the error does not occur...

Comment: I don't think disposed objects should continue to be used. Can you set the view's data context to null first (5), do any other unwiring of the view, then dispose the view (2) ?